# Nginx https and non-www results in many redirect loop

Tags: nginx, https

I am trying to do the following things

- force www. in my urls
- 301 redirect to https

I am getting too many redirects error when i go to www.example.com. When i go to example.com, it works fine.

Not sure where i went wrong. below is my server block code.

```
server {
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}    


server {
    server_name www.mydomain.com
    ...
}
```

Comment: Fix up your question please. It has example.com, www.example.com, and mydomain.com which seems unrelated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I do redirects to https://www.example.com

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/fullchain;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/privkey;

  # Set up preferred protocols and ciphers. TLS1.2 is required for HTTP/2
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  // locations etc
}

# This server simply redirects the requested to the https version of the page
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/fullchain;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/privkey;

  # Set up preferred protocols and ciphers. TLS1.2 is required for HTTP/2
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the configuration! appreciate it greatly.